# WPF DocumentViewer control loses icons when changing template, how to show icons

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls

I am tryng to add 2 new buttons to a document viewer control that us then hosted in a  windows form, so I took the template from MSDN to modify, but the all the "inbuilt" standard buttons turn to text on display rather than the icons.  I am wondering if anyone can please help me with why this happens and how to fix it as I have not been able to determine that from MSDN documentation.  However I am a newbie to XAML.  Below is the xaml for the modified control.

```
<UserControl
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:Documents="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Documents;assembly=PresentationUI" x:Class="AddinXPSViewer.XPSBrowser" 
      xmlns:self="clr-namespace:AddinXPSViewer"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      >
    <Frame x:Name="DocFrame">
        <Frame.Content>
            <Grid>
                <DocumentViewer x:Name="docViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0" Unloaded="docViewer_Unloaded" Style="{DynamicResource DocumentViewerStyle}" ContextMenu="{x:Null}" >
                    <DocumentViewer.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="DocumentViewerStyle" TargetType="DocumentViewer">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DocumentViewer">
                                            <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <ToolBar 
              ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" 
              KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
                                                    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" 
                CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                Content="Copy"/>
                                                    <Separator />
                                                    <Button Command="NavigationCommands.IncreaseZoom" 
                CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                Content="Zoom In"/>
                                                    <Button Command="NavigationCommands.DecreaseZoom" 
                CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                Content="Zoom Out"/>
                                                    <Separator />
                                                    <Button Command="NavigationCommands.Zoom" 
                CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                CommandParameter="100.0" 
                Content="Actual Size" />
                                                    <Button Command="DocumentViewer.FitToWidthCommand" 
                CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                Content="Fit to Width" />
                                                    <Button Command="DocumentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcrossCommand" 
                CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                CommandParameter="1" 
                Content="Whole Page"/>
                                                    <Button Command="DocumentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcrossCommand" 
                CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                CommandParameter="2" 
                Content="Two Pages"/>


                                                <Button Command="self:XPSBrowserCustomCommands.Next">Previous</Button>
                                                <Button Command="self:XPSBrowserCustomCommands.Previous">Next</Button>
                                            </ToolBar>

                                                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
              CanContentScroll="true"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
              IsTabStop="true"/>

                                                <ContentControl Grid.Row="2"
              x:Name="PART_FindToolBarHost"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>


                    </DocumentViewer.Resources>
                    <DocumentViewer.CommandBindings>
                        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Print" Executed="CommandBinding_OnPrint" />
                        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Print" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecutePrint" />
                        <CommandBinding Command="self:XPSBrowserCustomCommands.Next" Executed="CommandBinding_OnPrevious" />
                        <CommandBinding Command="self:XPSBrowserCustomCommands.Next" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecutePrevious" />
                        <CommandBinding Command="self:XPSBrowserCustomCommands.Previous" Executed="CommandBinding_OnNext" />
                        <CommandBinding Command="self:XPSBrowserCustomCommands.Previous" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecuteNext" />
                    </DocumentViewer.CommandBindings>
                </DocumentViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Frame.Content>
    </Frame>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

The secret is to right click and edit the Template or a copy of the Template twice in visual studio, this gives a different template to the one on msdn, and access to the sub controls for the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

On each `Button` the `Content` property is set to a string value.
e.g. `Content="Copy"`

If you want it to be an image you will have to set it to an `Image` control.

e.g.

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="copy.png"/>
</Button>
```

The 'default templates' on MSDN are not the actual default templates from WPF. They are just sample code for making your own control template.